# Open ajax dialog with JavaScript

Tags: ajax, modal-dialogs

By adding `use-ajax` to a link we can open a modal using the Drupal ajax library as per the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/ajax-dialog-boxes).

E.g.

```
<a class="use-ajax" 
    data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:400}" 
    data-dialog-type="modal" 
    href="/node/1">
    First article displayed in modal dialog.
</a>
```

This will use the ajax library to fetch node/1 and then display it in a modal.

There is also a [Dialog API for JavaScript](https://www.drupal.org/node/1852224) which allows opening modals using JavaScript.

E.g.

```
var myDialog  = Drupal.dialog(ADOMElement, settings);
myDialog.show();
```

The problem with this API is you need to pass in a existing DOM element.

My question is can I trigger opening a modal with JavaScript and utalise the internal Drupal ajax library to actually fetch the content?

E.g Can I do something like this?

```
var myDialog  = Drupal.dialog('/node/1', {useAjax: true});
myDialog.show();
```

I could just create an html link as per my first code block, hide it with css, and then trigger a click on it with JS but this seems a bit hacky - there must be a way to trigger this action using pure JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can trigger Ajax in custom javascript. See [How to Trigger Existing, Non-Form Ajax from JavaScript Event](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230312/how-to-trigger-existing-non-form-ajax-from-javascript-event)

In your case an Ajax dialog:

```
var ajaxSettings = {
  url: '/node/1',
  dialogType: 'modal',
  dialog: { width: 400 },
};
var myAjaxObject = Drupal.ajax(ajaxSettings);
myAjaxObject.execute();
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but how do you attach behaviours to this modal ?