# Refresh ( or reopen) a Dialog (meida browser) with javascript

Tags: ajax, 9, modal-dialogs

I have a media field, which when the user clicks on it, the media selector will open with the list of media.

I have a custom button there which do some ajax calls at the end I want to refresh the content of the Dialog ( Media browser Modal).

**Question: How in the javascript file we can detect the open dialog and refresh it?**
( because I want to see the latest updates)

I see there are some ways to trigger open a link on a dialog [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/ajax-dialog-boxes) and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296820/open-ajax-dialog-with-javascript) but it's different from what I wanted. I want to reopen opened Dialog ( media browser).
[image]

I took a look at the modal ajax command,

```
[{command: "settings",…},…]
0: {command: "settings",…}
1: {command: "update_build_id", old: "form-Un8r-lGuizetNMAm2fi418NHrJF0v28SSLOXsfh-04o",…}
2: {command: "openDialog", selector: "#drupal-modal", settings: null,…}
command: "openDialog"
data: "<div id=\"media-library-wrapper\" class=\"media-l
dialogOptions: {dialogClass: "media-library-widget-modal", title: "Add or select media", height: "75%", width: "75%",…}
dialogClass: "media-library-widget-modal"
height: "75%"
modal: true
title: "Add or select media"
width: "75%"
selector: "#drupal-modal"
settings: null
```

how can I Refresh(or reopen) an opened Dialog ( Media library) in custom Js file?

**Update:**

an idea,
in js, get "field_name" of modal from action, then try to trigger "mousedown" action on the button. but looks like no very good solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for resolving this, I noticed the `action` of the modal `form` contains several parameters, one of that is `fieldName` which shows which field caused modal open.

```
/media-library?
media_library_opener_id=media_library.opener.field_widget&
media_library_allowed_types%5Bpicture_park%5D=picture_park&media_library_selected_type=picture_park&
media_library_remaining=1
&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bfield_widget_id%5D=field_meida_2
&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bentity_type_id%5D=node&
media_library_opener_parameters%5Bbundle%5D=article&
media_library_opener_parameters%5Bfield_name%5D=field_meida_2&
hash=bGb3mXT_TI82FjHJbQYkJUm_UpaRXAQYNQYa0iZ7skM
```

So, in the Js file, I detect file name, then find button and just trigger `mousedown` action on that.

```
jQuery("input[data-media-library-widget-value=" + fieldName + "]").parent().find(".media-library-open-button").trigger("mousedown");
```

```
  function getUrlVars(url) {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
  }
```

with this solution it's possible to refresh the Dialog in a custom javascript.