# How can I render a form via javascript without outputting the entire page markup

Tags: 8, forms, javascript

I'm trying to load a custom form into a div, but when I do, the entire page markup (menu, header, footer, etc) is being output in the div. Is there a way I can only output the form?

This is my javascript call:

```
jQuery('#tile-form-container .content').load('/tile/edit/2');
```

This is my route:

```
tiles.edit:
  path: 'tile/edit/{id}'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Edit tile'
    _form: '\Drupal\tiles\Form\TileForm'
  options:
    _admin_route: true
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer tiles'
```

In my buildForm function I have added this line:

```
$form['theme'] = 'tile_form';
```

And that file looks like this:

```
<div id="tile-form">
    <div id="tile-form-container">
        <div class="content">
            {{ form }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To handle Form API forms you need Drupal.ajax() instead of jQuery.load(). I think with that question you've asked earlier you were closer to a solution: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296949/how-do-i-render-a-form-in-a-div-through-a-javascript-call

Comment: That's what jquery load will do.